How do I get the program to give the user another chance after entering the incorrect detail?
Instead of giving the user 3 chances it just prints access denied 3 times but I am not sure how to change the code so that it would give the user 3 chances and also it prints welcome even if the user enters the incorrect details so I would be grateful if someone could help me with this
Tbh i am a very novice programmer so I was not expecting it to work but if it did work i would have expected it to give the user 3 chances and if they get all the chances wrong then it would print something along the lines of "Account locked out"
username = "Student1"
password = "WatfordLenMein"
input1 = input("Enter username: ")
input2 = input("Enter password: ")
for i in range(3):
    if username == input1 and password == input2:
        break
    else:
        print("Access denied")
print("Welcome")


You have to put the input() calls inside the loop so that once user gives the wrong username and password, the program again asks for username and password. For the second part, I think you can set some flag before the break and check it outside the loop

As "kuro" mentioned you have to put the input() function inside the for-loop to check three times if the input is correct:
username = "Student1"
password = "WatfordLenMein"

for i in range(3):

    input1 = input("Enter username: ")
    input2 = input("Enter password: ")

    if username == input1 and password == input2:
        print("Welcome")
        break
    else:
        print("Access denied")


Your code should rather look like this:
username = "Student1"
password = "WatfordLenMein"

is_login_successful = False

for i in range(3):
    # ask the user to enter login/password on every iteration of the loop.
    # if you keep this outside, then the user will be prompted to enter
    # credentials only once .. which is not what you want.
    input1 = input("Enter username: ")
    input2 = input("Enter password: ")

    # if the login/password match, then the loop is over
    if username == input1 and password == input2:
        is_login_successful = True
        break
    else:
        print("Access denied")

# as suggested by kuro, the use of a flag simplifies the overall logic
if (not is_login_successful):
    print("Account locked out")
    exit(1)

print("Welcome")
...


You need the inputs to be inside the for loop. This is also a good use-case for the for/else construct.
username = "Student1"
password = "WatfordLenMein"

for _ in range(3):
    u = input("Enter username: ")
    p = input("Enter password: ")
    if u == username and p == password:
        print("Welcome")
        break
else:
    # This will be executed if the for loop terminates due to range exhaustion - i.e., no break
    print("Access denied")

The only problem with this is that once you're outside the loop you don't know if you got there with a valid username/password or you had too many retries but that's outside of the scope of your question
